# 'ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 3 but received input

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am getting an error when I'm training my cnn on an array of skimage.feature.hog images. The data set I'm using has 3 RGB values and these have 1 value instead. Which is effectively a subset of the dataset I am using. I suspect the issue arises from me using the same code from my original cnn on the 'full' dataset, or something to do with the dimensions? I cannot figure it out even though there are similar threads, I apologize if this is simplistic question. I believe I have specified the dimensions, of the new hog training and testing subsets, correctly.
Any help would be appreciated.
The error is : ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 3 but received input with shape [None, 32, 32, 1]

```
hog_trn= np.zeros(10240000).reshape(10000,32,32,1)
hog_tst = np.zeros(1024000).reshape(1000,32,32,1)
for i in range(10000):
    hog_feature, hog_image = skimage.feature.hog(trn_images[i,:,:,:], pixels_per_cell=[2,2], cells_per_block=[3,3], visualize=True)
    hog_trn[i,:,:,0] = hog_image
for i in range(1000):
    hog_feature, hog_image = skimage.feature.hog(tst_images[i,:,:,:], pixels_per_cell=[2,2], cells_per_block=[3,3], visualize=True)
    hog_tst[i,:,:,0] = hog_image

model_hog = models.Sequential()
model_hog.add(layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation = 'relu',input_shape=(32,32,1)))
model_hog.add(layers.MaxPool2D((2,2)))
model_hog.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model_hog.add(layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2)))
model_hog.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model_hog.add(layers.Flatten())
model_hog.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model_hog.add(layers.Dense(10))
model_hog.summary()

model_hog.compile(optimizer='Adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history_hog = model.fit(hog_trn, trn_labels, epochs=10, 
                    validation_data=(hog_tst, tst_labels))
plt.plot(history_hog.history['accuracy'], label='accuracy')
plt.plot(history_hog.history['val_accuracy'], label = 'val_accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(hog_tst,  tst_labels, verbose=2)
```

And the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-b829133dd6d6> in <module>
     14               metrics=['accuracy'])
     15 
---> 16 history_hog = model.fit(hog_trn, trn_labels, epochs=10, 
     17                     validation_data=(hog_tst, tst_labels))
     18 plt.plot(history_hog.history['accuracy'], label='accuracy')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1096                 batch_size=batch_size):
   1097               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1098               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
   1099               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1100                 context.async_wait()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    778       else:
    779         compiler = "nonXla"
--> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    781 
    782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    805       # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
    806       # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
--> 807       return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    808     elif self._stateful_fn is not None:
    809       # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2826     """Calls a graph function specialized to the inputs."""
   2827     with self._lock:
-> 2828       graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2829     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2830 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3208           and self.input_signature is None
   3209           and call_context_key in self._function_cache.missed):
-> 3210         return self._define_function_with_shape_relaxation(args, kwargs)
   3211 
   3212       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _define_function_with_shape_relaxation(self, args, kwargs)
   3139           expand_composites=True)
   3140 
-> 3141     graph_function = self._create_graph_function(
   3142         args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes=relaxed_arg_shapes)
   3143     self._function_cache.arg_relaxed[rank_only_cache_key] = graph_function

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3063     arg_names = base_arg_names + missing_arg_names
   3064     graph_function = ConcreteFunction(
-> 3065         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
   3066             self._name,
   3067             self._python_function,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    984         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    985 
--> 986       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    987 
    988       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    598         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    599         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 600         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    601     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    602 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    971           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    972             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 973               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    974             else:
    975               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:747 train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:975 __call__
        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs,
    C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\input_spec.py:212 assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 3 but received input with shape [None, 32, 32, 1]
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct code? Because your code does not match with the error message

Comment: I believe so. The code in the error is only one line from the actual code and they look the same to me. Could you point out what you were referring to? Thanks

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy sorry forgot to tag you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate the your issue with sample code below

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()

# Normalize pixel values to be between 0 and 1
train_images, test_images = train_images / 255.0, test_images / 255.0

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10, 
                    validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
```

Output

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_3 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape (None, 32, 32, 3)
```

**Working sample code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()

# Normalize pixel values to be between 0 and 1
train_images, test_images = train_images / 255.0, test_images / 255.0
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10, 
                    validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
```

Output

```
Epoch 1/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 57s 35ms/step - loss: 1.4933 - accuracy: 0.4563 - val_loss: 1.2447 - val_accuracy: 0.5506
Epoch 2/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 7s 5ms/step - loss: 1.1281 - accuracy: 0.5992 - val_loss: 1.0636 - val_accuracy: 0.6278
Epoch 3/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.9782 - accuracy: 0.6554 - val_loss: 0.9508 - val_accuracy: 0.6649
Epoch 4/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 6s 4ms/step - loss: 0.8905 - accuracy: 0.6876 - val_loss: 0.9210 - val_accuracy: 0.6790
Epoch 5/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 8s 5ms/step - loss: 0.8242 - accuracy: 0.7104 - val_loss: 0.9869 - val_accuracy: 0.6544
Epoch 6/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 6s 4ms/step - loss: 0.7660 - accuracy: 0.7313 - val_loss: 0.9100 - val_accuracy: 0.6911
Epoch 7/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 6s 4ms/step - loss: 0.7188 - accuracy: 0.7478 - val_loss: 0.8901 - val_accuracy: 0.6936
Epoch 8/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 7s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6764 - accuracy: 0.7621 - val_loss: 0.9099 - val_accuracy: 0.6844
Epoch 9/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 6s 4ms/step - loss: 0.6420 - accuracy: 0.7744 - val_loss: 0.8895 - val_accuracy: 0.6983
Epoch 10/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 8s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6000 - accuracy: 0.7909 - val_loss: 0.8978 - val_accuracy: 0.7023
```

Problem with this line `model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 1)))`
Input dataset has `RGB` images input_shape should be `(32,32,3)` where 3 stands for 3 RGB channels and whereas '1' is used for grayscale image